# reading PNG using ImageIO input null exception

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I'm trying to create a basic implementation of *Pacman* for my Java course, and have created a test project just to get the movement working (for now). I'm going to try moving a `JLabel` across a panel, and am trying to set the icon of the `JLabel` to be a PNG file that I've loaded into the project. The PNG file is in a folder named *Images*, and all my other classes are in the *src* folder in the same project. When I try to read the PNG files from my *src* folder classes I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1400)
    at pacman.<init>(pacman.java:16)
    at screen.<init>(screen.java:9)
    at driver.main(driver.java:6)
```

The `driver` creates a `screen` object that then creates a `pacman` object and the error points to the `pacman` class which is below:

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class pacman {
    Point pacLoc= new Point(0,0);
    Direction pacDir=Direction.RIGHT;
    int pacLives;
    static int count=1;
    int pacID;
    BufferedImage pactest;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    pacman(){
        pacID=count;
        switch(pacID) {
        case 1:
            try {
                pactest=ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Images/lolface.png"));
            } catch(IOException a1) {
                a1.printStackTrace();
            }
            pacLoc.setLocation(100,100);
            break;
        case 2:
            try {
                pactest=ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Images/whyface.png"));
            } catch(IOException a1) {
                a1.printStackTrace();
            }
            pacLoc.setLocation(100,200);
            break;
        }
        count++;
    }
}
```

The error stems (I think) from `ImageIO` not finding the PNG files. Do I have to import them into my `pacman` class somehow? What would be the import syntax in that case? I should mention that I'm using Eclipse IDE and am trying to avoid using any external libraries for the sake of simplicity.

### Edit:

The other 2 classes aren't too large at the moment so I can post them here as well if it helps at all.

### Edit 2:

Using `ImageIO.read(pacman.class.getResource("lolface.png"));` instead of `Images/lolface.png` works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getClass().getResource()` is incorrect; the proper syntax is `pacman.class.getResource(...)` where `pacman` is your own classname*.

Second point, your exception handling is broken. Exceptions contains 4 useful things (the type, the message, the stack trace, and the causal chain).

You're throwing away 3 out of the 4 things. Don't do that; either actually deal with it (logging or printing errors is **NOT** dealing with it!), or throw it onwards (put `throws IOException` on your method/constructor signature), or if that's no good either, go with `catch (Whatever e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }` which is not great but a heck of a lot better than `e.printStackTrace()`.

You do not have to import anything; import is aliasing type names (`import com.foo.Bar;` means: Anytime anywhere in this file `Bar` is written and indicates a type, imagine it read `com.foo.Bar` instead. It neither loads the Bar class into memory nor runs any code inside it, and it has nothing to do with resources).

Without a stack trace of the error we can't help you.

*IF* it is a nullpointerexception on the line that starts with `case 1` or the line that starts with `case 2`, yes, it's because the resource is not found.

Assuming you fixed the above issue (`pacman.class.getResource` instead of `getClass().getResource`) and this is still happening: the way getResource works is that it looks relative to the directory that contains `pacman.class`... even if said class is, say, inside a jar file. So, if you have, say, `/home/BotFred/workspace/com.botfred.pacman/build/com/botfred/pacman/pacman.class`, then, it expects the image to be at `/home/BotFred/workspace/com.botfred.pacman/build/com/botfred/pacman/Images/lolface.png`.

If you're not quite sure where pacman class is being loaded from, you can always do this to find out:

```
System.out.println(pacman.class.getResource("pacman.class"));
```

the printed result will be something like `file:///home/BotFred/workspace/com.botfred.pacman/build/com/botfred/pacman/pacman.class` or perhaps `jar:file:///home/BotFred/pacman.jar!com/foo/botfred/pacman.class` (which indicates where the jar is, and then within it, as jars are just zip files, which place; it would then look inside that jar at com/foo/botfred/Images/lolface.png for your image.

*) The reason is that getClass() goes by the actual type of the instantiated object, and not by the very code you're looking at. So, if you subclass, things break. Perhaps pacman is not currently subclassed, but the key word there is currently. Maybe one day it is. It'd suck if it breaks all of a sudden. Best learn the good habit from the getgo; always use `myclassname.class.getResource` because that matches what you're trying to accomplish (which is: Use a resource that is stored in the same place the class file this code is in is stored).

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer! I just tried pacman.class.getResource instead and the error persisted. I'll try handling the exception in the way you described next and get back to you. The pacman class is in Pacman/src/pacman.java, and the PNGs are in Pacman/Images/asd.png
Edit: running Sys.println produced: file:/C:/*censored*/eclipse-workspace/Pacman/bin/pacman.class

Comment: I think I see the issue. The Images folder is not inside the bin(or src) folder that all my other classes are in. Both folders are at the same layer. So the way I understand it is that right now it's looking for an Images folder thats inside the same folder as pacman.class, when the folder I want it to find is one layer up?

Comment: Put the images in the same place as the java source files (so, src/Images/asd.png, not /Images/asd.png); eclipse will automatically copy them over to the bin there. It's not possible to use getResource and go 'one layer up', but letting eclipse copy them over will work.